# VBS not opening WinSCP and getting file via SFTP

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, sftp, winscp

We have some scripts which have been running just fine on 2003 sever.  Its a Windows Scheduled Task which calls a .bat file, this file connects opens the WinSCP console and used a stored session to SFTP to a location and retrieve some files like so:

```
winscp.com /script=SFTPScript.txt > SFTP_log_%All%.log
```

and then does stuff..... The version of WinSCP on the 2003 box is 4.5.1 (build 410).  This is all working well.  While moving other scripts I discover 2008 R2 likes the full path so have changed the above line of code to this:

```
D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\WinSCP\winscp.com /script=D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\SFTPScript.txt
```

When I place a pause in the vbs file and look at the console it gets to this line and prints:

```
batch  on
confirm  off
Searching for host...

Network error: Connection times out
No session
No session
```

Here are the four variations I have tried:

```
rem winscp.com /script=SFTPScript.txt > SFTP_log_%All%.log
rem D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\WinSCP\winscp.com /script=SFTPScript.txt > SFTP_log_%All%.log
rem D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\WinSCP\winscp.com /script=D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\SFTPScript.txt > SFTP_log_%All%.log
rem D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\WinSCP\winscp.exe /console /script=SFTPScript.txt D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\WinSCP\winscp.com /script=D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\SFTPScript.txt
```

The version of WinSCP on the 2008 R2 server is 5.5.1 (Build 3970).  I have 100% confirmed that the stored session details are connecting succesfully.  I can open WinSCP and fire the session without any issue, no password prompts, it direct connects.  Yes the winscp.exe and the winscp.com files are in the same dir....

Hopefully someone can assit???

Comment: Start with reading http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler. Particularly the part about `/log`. Compare logs from 4.5.1 and 5.5.1. Share the log with us if it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

After ALL day on this it is now working with this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=D:\inetpub\Scripts\Citibank\SFTPScript.txt
```

This makes not sense to me at all...

Comment: Chances are that your firewall allows a copy of `winscp.com` in `Program Files`, but blocks a copy in `inetpub`.